# Accelerate assigning of probability densities given two values in Python 3

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

For some of my research, I need to assign a probability density given a value, a mean, and a standard deviation, except I need to do this about 40 million times, so accelerating this code is becoming critical to working in a productive fashion.

I have only 10 values to test (values = 10x1 matrix), but I want to assign a probability for each of these values given a total of 4 million truncated normal distributions per value, each with varying means (all_means = 4 million x 10 matrix), and the same standard deviation (error = 1 value). The code I've been using to do this so far is below:

```
import scipy.stats as ss

all_probabilities =[]

for row in all_means:

    temp_row = []
    for i in range(len(row)):

        # Isolate key values
        mean = row[i]
        error = 0.05
        value = values[i]

        # Create truncated normal distribution and calculate PMF
        a, b = 0, np.inf
        mu, sigma = float(mean), float(error)
        alpha, beta = ((a-mu)/sigma), ((b-mu)/sigma)
        prob = ss.truncnorm.pdf(float(value), alpha, beta, loc=mu, scale=sigma)
        temp_row.extend([prob])

    all_probabilities.extend([temp_row])
```

A single loop takes an average of 5ms, but to do this 4 million times, means this section of code would take about 5 hours to complete. I assume the limiting factors are in calling ss.truncnorm.pdf, and using extend. The latter I can get around by pre-allocating the probability matrix, but the former I see no work around for.

For more context, this bit of code is part of an algorithm which uses this code an average of 5 times (albeit with a rapidly decreasing number of distributions to test), so any tips to speed up this code would be a huge help.

Apologies if this is trivial, I'm relatively new to optimizing code, and could not find anything on this sort of problem specifically.

Comment: I'd say that profiling your function with something like the example here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html would be a good place to start, to be sure which steps are in fact taking the most time.

Comment: There are 3 main strategies - reduce the number iterations, speed up each iteration (`ss.truncnorm.pdf` is most likely the key), or evaluate multiple cases 'at-once'.  Without digging into `ss.truncnorm.pdf` it's hard to say whether the last 2 are possible.    5ms for a relatively complex `scipy` function sounds reasonable.  Doing something a million times is not good python/numpy.

Comment: I can't reduce the number of iterations for reasons related to it's application, and it seems like the latter two aren't possible (or at least not easily so) with scipy stats, but I just switched to tensorflow which easily enables the 'at-once' feature and sped this up dramatically.

I'll post a detailed answer to my own question once I've finished working out some kinks.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the inner loop as `scipy.stats.truncnorm` can be defined as a vector of random variables i.e.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import truncnorm

all_probabilities = []
a, b = 0, np.inf
error = 0.05

for row in all_means:

    alpha, beta = ((a-row )/error), ((b-row )/error)

    # vectorized truncnorm
    rv_tn = truncnorm(alpha, beta, loc=row, scale=error)

    # predict vector
    prob = rv_tn.pdf(values)

    all_probabilities.extend(prob)
```